# VS2010 RDLC Body Background Image Preview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I've created a Report (RDLC) in VS2010 and have selected an embedded image as the Body "Background Image" but I do not see a preview of that image when working with the RDLC designer.  Doesn't seem to make any difference if I select an "External" image file either - still no preview in the designer.

Is there a switch somewhere that I have to flip to make VS2010 show me the background image in the report designer, or is there no way to see the body background image at design time?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to set the according MIMEType from the dropdown in properties section, Fill subsection:

- image/bmp
- image/jpeg
- image/gif
- image/png
- image/x-png

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154003%28v=sql.90%29.aspx